# How to configure iptables for a dial-up VPN with OpenVPN and two interfaces?

Tags: centos, iptables, openvpn, linux-networking

I have an AWS EC2 instance, running Amazon Linux, that has two Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs) attached: eth0 and eth1. I am connecting to the public IP on eth0. Everything works great, except I would like to route unencrypted traffic out of the eth1. i.e. Client connects to eth0 to setup an encrypted VPN tunnel, then his/her unencrypted internet traffic is routed in/out of eth1 and back across the tunnel on eth0.

I don't know enough about iptables to get this config working, despite trying for several hours. I'm hoping this is a simple one?

I've installed the latest version of OpenVPN from source and done the following:

1. Disabled source/dest check on the interfaces
2. Added the following to "rc.local": `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
3. Added the following iptables commands:

   `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.18.14.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

My server config file looks like this:

```
port 443
proto tcp-server
dev tun
tls-server
server 10.18.14.0 255.255.255.0

ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/vpnserver.crt
key /etc/openvpn/pki/vpnserver.key
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp2.txt 
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 5 15
comp-lzo
max-clients 5
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn_road.log
verb 6 
mute 20

tun-mtu 1500
auth SHA1
keysize 128
cipher BF-CBC
```

Comment: In `FORWARD` and `POSTROUTING` rules try to change eth0 to eth1. Also, I think you don't need the second `FORWARD` rule (tun+, RELATED,ESTABLISHED)  as the one before it matches every time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup routing, your rules look ok but you need to change the MASQ rule.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.18.14.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

I would also suggest some simpler rules for your originating packets.

```
# Allows packets from connections initiated by the box or already established
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Now as for the routing I assume you only want the OpenVPN clients to exit via eth1 and not the server it self that I presume has it's default route via eth0. We need to create a new routing table for your OpenVPN clients, we will call it ovpn-inet.

Edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, insert the following at the end and save.

```
1 ovpn-inet
```

Then create `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` with the following content, replacing `<gw on eth1>` and other attributes within `<>`.

```
default via <gw for eth1> dev eth1 table ovpn-inet
<local network on eth1> dev eth1 src <eth1 ip adress> table ovpn-inet
```

Now create `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1`

```
from <ip address of eth1>/32 table ovpn-inet
from 10.18.14.0/24 table ovpn-inet
to <ip address of eth1>/32 table ovpn-inet
```

A suggestion would also be to switch OpenVPN to UDP for the sake of performance. This would also allow you to run a HTTPS server if you ever need it over TCP. Also consider using a `tls-crypt` in your OpenVPN server config as a simple way of doing a little hardening on your installation.

```
proto udp4
```

Now restart your networking to make the changes in effect.

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```